# Pattern recognition - machine recognition of plausible shape of a polygon

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, machine-learning, computational-geometry

I have a schoolproject where the task is to locate all possible shapes (of a certain complex polygonic structure) in a layer of several heterogenous polygons.

[image: Cadastral polygon]

And now the task is to find all the ones that assimilate (more or less)

[image: Highlighted examples]

[image: Detailed example]

Starting from above the exact tools, I think we are dealing with a machine-learning concept here. I've looked at Grass-GIS [GeoMorphon](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/addons/r.geomorphon.html) and it seems that it has the potential to start using as a tool. However I have never tried such an advanced task before. I have also considered OpenCV to maybe provide me with a solution, however the libraries for pattern recognition is based on raster photos and perhaps not suited for a vector-scaled dataset.

So far I've been filtering out all polygons <= 6 vertices after having done a (dangerous) simplification of the polygons. That reduced the number of polygons left to about 60 %. But there is still a long way to go and I have no idea of how to progress.

Comment: What exactly is the task? I think you left a crucial word out of your question. It says, "the task is to _______ all possible shapes." Please fill in the blank.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "assimilate"? This looks like parcel data. Are you trying to find properties where one property has only a narrow strip for road access?

Comment: You could compare the ratio of circumference to area. Polygons with a long narrow strip extending off of the main body will have a higher ratio than polygons that are more compact.

Comment: @csk interesting proposal. I'd look into that and see if there is a pattern.

Comment: See also https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.to.db.html which offers vector line statistics.